# Android 7.0 init.rc mediaserver

Tags: android, server, system, boot, android-7.0-nougat

I have question about Android 7.0 boot sequence.

In Android 6.0, the init process will parse the init.rc and initiate the mediaserver:

```
service media /system/bin/mediaserver
    class main
    user main
    group audio camera inet net_bt net_bt_admin net_bw_acct drmrpc mediadrm qcom_diag radio cw_access
    ...
```

But in Android 7.0, the init.rc doesn't have the above code, so i wondering who is the one initiate the mediaserver?? could be systemserver or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a file named *mediaserver.rc* in *frameworks/native*. Android 7.0 tryes to separate the *init.rc* actions and services according to reason. And you'll find them in *system/etc/init/* on the device.